# How to set default fallbacks for mobility?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobility

I saw on the Github documentation of Mobility that it is possible to set default fallbacks for Mobility. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
Mobility.configure do |config|
  config.default_backend = :table
  config.accessor_method = :translates
  config.default_fallbacks = { fr: :en, de: :en, nl: :en, en: :nl, es: :en, cn: :en }
end
```

But when I start the Rails console it will give me a no method error:

```
`default_fallbacks': undefined method `call' for {:fr=>:en, :de=>:en, :nl=>:en, :en=>:nl, :es=>:en, :cn=>:en}:Hash (NoMethodError)
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Have you tried making your hash keys strings? i.e. `fr: 'en', de: 'en'`?

Comment: it looks to me the code is trying to execute a `block` in your `Hash` instance, so, perhaps `default_fallbacks` needs a block.

Comment: take a look here https://github.com/shioyama/mobility/blob/33fa165fe8344c52be3910a2210a290251797e92/lib/mobility/configuration.rb#L64

Comment: You are right @fanta, it has to be a block. I changed it to this: `config.default_fallbacks = Proc.new { |fallbacks| { fr: :en, de: :en, nl: :en, en: :nl, es: :en, cn: :en } }`. The server starts but the default fallbacks are not working, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on this is not very good. To set default fallbacks, you should set the value for the `fallbacks` key on the `default_options` configuration option, like this:

```
Mobility.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.default_options[:fallbacks] = { fr: :en, de: :en, nl: :en, en: :nl, es: :en, cn: :en }
end
```

The `default_fallbacks` configuration is for if you want to use a different fallback instance instead of `I18n::Locale::Fallbacks.new`.